# Formula to ignore blank cells and calculate cells having numbers only

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a Formula to calculate cells having numbers only and ignore blank cells. 
The condition is between two cells, IF there is a value in `A column` then **ADDITION** should take place or IF there is value in `B column` then **SUBTRACTION** should take place

Case 1:

```
A2(number),B2(Empty),C2=(C1+A2) {Ignoring B2 as blank cell}
```

Case 2:

```
A2(Empty),B2(number),C2=(C1-B2) {Ignoring A2 as blank cell}
```

Kindly suggest appropriate formula to the above condition. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following formula in cell `C2`:

```
=IFNA(IFS(ISNUMBER(A2),C1+A2,ISNUMBER(B2),C1-B2),)
```

Functions used:

- [`IFNA`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9365944)
- [`IFS`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7014145)
- [`ISNUMBER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296)